# How to create Vertical Radio Button Group in html form without table tag

Tags: html

How to create vertical Radio Button Group instead of horizontal button group in an html form?

I don't want to use a table for this. Is there any property/attribute available?

Any type of help/suggestion would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There are three ways you can do it: two with CSS or 1 with oldschool html:

1) The preferred way would be to use a CSS class. (ie add *class="block"* to the element and then *.block {display:block}* to your stylesheet.

2)Inline styles: Add *style="display:block"* to the element.

3)HTML: Add a hard break (br) element after the radio element (or enclose the elements each in a div or p element.)

Example:

```
<style type="text/css">
   .block {
      display: block;
   }
</style>
```

...

```
<form>
<label class="block"><input type="radio" name="radgroup" value="A">Option A</label>
<label class="block"><input type="radio" name="radgroup" value="B">Option B</label>
<label class="block"><input type="radio" name="radgroup" value="C">Option C</label>
<label class="block"><input type="radio" name="radgroup" value="D">Option D</label>
</form>
```

Comment: I would add that you can do this with css without defining a new css class. Simply use a selector, such as `form label` in the case above, if the html structure allows, then apply `display: block`

Comment: very true... I've never been a huge fan of applying css directly to html elements myself though. I tend to gravitate towards BEM (http://getbem.com/).